# Getting "Error" while trying to connect Ionic App with Mobile first server 7.1 version

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I am New to Ionic + Mobile first.I have developed my Ionic App. In there i have to connect my App with mobile first server 7.1 version.

While connecting the server using "WL.Client.connect()" Method, i am not getting any alert either "success or fail" in the method callback.

```
 WL.Client.connect({
       onSuccess: successCallback,
       onFailure: failureCallback
   });
   function  successCallback()
   {
       alert("success");
   }

   function  failureCallback()
   {
       alert("fail");
   }
```

My sample,
https://github.com/Smohanapriya/Ionic-with-Mobile-first-7.1-version/blob/master/www/js/app.js

Everyone help will be Appreciated!!!

Comment: how you get device information? if you do not run ,emulator or device

Comment: I run my app via device only :)

Answer (score 0):

`WLAuthorizationManager` is v8.0 beta API.
If you use 7.1, use `WL.client.connect()`.

Please, you are asking very basic questions.
You need to read the tutorials. It does not matter if you develop a Hybrid or Cordova or Ionic or with Studio or CLI. You need to learn the basics, from there it is all the same.

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/hello-world/connecting-to-mobilefirst-server/

Comment: I am new to this Mobile first. My question was updated.